# Add wysiwyg editor to custom taxonomy pages

Tags: custom-post-type, wysiwyg, custom-taxonomy

I have created a custom taxonomy called **collection**. Now, I want to add WYSIWYG editor to it. I came across this code on [Github](https://gist.github.com/dasbairagya/b8ab342418981bc8d083b23734474007)
and it works fine on product category pages. I would want to implement the same code to my custom taxonomy term, **collection**. How do I go about this? I tried to replace product_cat with product_archive but the PHP editor could not save it and I received an error notice in return.  tis is the error,
***Unable to communicate back with site to check for fatal errors, so the PHP change was reverted. You will need to upload your PHP file change by some other means, such as by using SFTP.***

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.